# How to create a looping shuffle method in an array

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, shuffle

I am stuck trying to make a deck shuffling method. I searched for answers on Stack Overflow but have not been able to figure it out.

I want to create a shuffle method. This method will pick two random numbers from the array between 0 and the size of the deck. I then want the two numbers to be passed as parameters to my swap() method. I want to create a loop so that the swap method gets called  TIMES_TO_SHUFFLE times. What is the best way to do this?

This is the Deck class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Deck of cards.   
 * @author Stefan
 * @version 2014.11.19
 */
public class Deck {   
    private ArrayList<Card> deck;

    public static final int TIMES_TO_SHUFFLE = 10;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Deck
     * Creates a new container for Card objects
     */
    public Deck() {
        deck = new ArrayList<Card>();    
    }

    /**
     * Swap two cards that the user chooses.
     */   
    public void swap(int indexA, int indexB) {
        Card temp = deck.get (indexA);
        deck.set(indexA, deck.get (indexB)); 
        deck.set(indexB, temp); 
    }

    /**
     * Shuffles two cards by passing parameters to the swapCards method
     */
    private void shuffle() {

    }

    /**
     * Add a card to the deck.
     * @param Card to be added
     */
    public void addCard(Card cardToAdd) {
        deck.add(cardToAdd);
    }

    /**
     * Take the first card from the deck.
     * @return Card or null
     */
    public Card takeCard()  {
        if(deck.isEmpty()) {
            return null; 
        } else {  
        // get the top card
            return deck.remove(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the contents of the deck.
     */
   public void showDeck()  {
        for(Card eachCard : deck) {
            System.out.println(eachCard.getDescription()+ 
            " of " + eachCard.getSuit());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Card class.

```
/**
 * Card class - a typical playing card.
 * 
 * @author Stefan
 * @version 2014.11.18
 */
public class Card {
    private String suit;
    private int value;
    private String description;

    /**
     * @default constructor
     */
    public Card(){
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Card
     * @param suit e.g. "Hearts"
     * @param value e.g. 10
     * @param description e.g. "Ten"
     */
    public Card(String description, String suit, int value) {
        this.suit           = suit;
        this.value          = value;
        this.description    = description;
    }

    /**
     * @return the suit
     */
    public String getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    /**
     * @param suit the suit to set
     */
    public void setSuit(String suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    /**
     * @return the value
     */
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * @param value the value to set
     */
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * @return the description
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * @param description the description to set
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

Comment: Apply [Collections.shuffle()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29) to the deck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shuffle method will look like this :

```
 private void shuffle() {
      Deck ob = new Deck();
      int x = deck.size() - 1;
      for(int i = 0; i < TIMES_TO_SHUFFLE + 1; i ++){
      int r1 = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * x);
      int r2 = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * x);
      ob.swap(r1, r2);
}
    }
```

Comment: I accepted your answer. I am fairly new to this site so I dont know all of the procedures yet.